# getting selenium html table into pandas dataframe with beautifulsoup

Tags: pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have successfully used selenium to scrape an html table which required a button click prior to scraping.

So selenium works, and successfully stores the html table as a variable ' r '.

I'm stumbling however getting this parsed into a pandas dataframe.

Like the URL, the dataframe should have 5 columns and about 30 rows.

Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/Users/computer_name/Documents/python/web_drivers/geckodriver')
browser.get('https://www.investing.com/equities/exxon-mobil-income-statement')
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Annual')
linkElem.click()
r = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#rrtable > table").get_attribute('innerHTML')
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame(soup)
print(df)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the `soup element` then use `pd.read_html()` You need to use `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML`

```
r = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#rrtable > table").get_attribute('outerHTML')
browser.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
                                     Period Ending:  ...                                          201631/12
0                                       Total Revenue  ...                                             200628
1   Revenue 255583 279332 237162 200628  Other Rev...  ...  Revenue 255583 279332 237162 200628  Other Rev...
2                                             Revenue  ...                                             200628
3                                Other Revenue, Total  ...                                                  -
4                              Cost of Revenue, Total  ...                                             136098
5                                        Gross Profit  ...                                              64530
6                            Total Operating Expenses  ...                                             199692
7   Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total 41923 4...  ...  Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total 41923 4...
8              Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total  ...                                              39819
9                              Research & Development  ...                                               1467
10                        Depreciation / Amortization  ...                                              22308
11          Interest Expense (Income) - Net Operating  ...                                                  -
12                           Unusual Expense (Income)  ...                                                  -
13                    Other Operating Expenses, Total  ...                                                  -
14                                   Operating Income  ...                                                936
15       Interest Income (Expense), Net Non-Operating  ...                                               4353
16                      Gain (Loss) on Sale of Assets  ...                                                  -
17                                         Other, Net  ...                                               2680
18                            Net Income Before Taxes  ...                                               7969
19                         Provision for Income Taxes  ...                                               -406
20                             Net Income After Taxes  ...                                               8375
21                                  Minority Interest  ...                                               -535
22                               Equity In Affiliates  ...                                                  -
23                                U.S GAAP Adjustment  ...                                                  -
24              Net Income Before Extraordinary Items  ...                                               7840
25                          Total Extraordinary Items  ...                                                  -
26                                         Net Income  ...                                               7840
27                    Total Adjustments to Net Income  ...                                                  -
28  Income Available to Common Excluding Extraordi...  ...                                               7840
29                                Dilution Adjustment  ...                                                  -
30                                 Diluted Net Income  ...                                               7840
31                    Diluted Weighted Average Shares  ...                                               4177
32          Diluted EPS Excluding Extraordinary Items  ...                                               1.88
33                   DPS - Common Stock Primary Issue  ...                                               2.98
34                             Diluted Normalized EPS  ...                                               1.88
```

Comment: I just stumbled across this answer, and it helped me. However, I'm not fully sure what the code is doing. First, can you help me understand what the outerHTML does? Second, can you help me understand why you add the 0 element to the end of the read html - pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]. Thanks in advance!